# Does this sentence regarding "coleopteran" make sense?

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

There's some ambiguity between Polish and English ( as far as beetles are concerned). Please help me determine if this sentence makes any sense at all.
Thank you.

> I know that a (forest) dung beetle can be called a coleopteran. Because every beetle is a coleopteran. But you need to know that not every coleopteran is a beetle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A (forest) dung beetle is a coleopteran, since every beetle is a coleopteran. One must remember, though, that not every coleopteran is a beetle.

Answer (score 2):

this is my first time contributing. I'd like to correct your sentence.

There is a misunderstanding that you should not start sentences with conjunctions (because). It is, in fact, not true, but it is more popular to use conjunctions to connect simple sentences. In this case, you have the following:

> I know that a (forest) dung beetle can be called a coleopteran.

and

> Because every beetle is a coleopteran.

These two are simple sentences. You can combine them with the word *because*. Remove the capital B in the second sentence, make it a lower case. Remove the period in the first sentence and add a comma.

The second correction to make is the phrase: **But you need to know that...** This sentence is not incorrect, but maybe be informal for typing. If there is a personal voice you are pursing, and you would like to write the sentence in the way you would like to, then you can leave the third sentence alone. The most common way to write it would most likely be this:

> I know that a (forest) dung beetle can be called a coleopteran, because every beetle is a coleopteran. However, it is important to know that not every coleopteran is a beetle.

Comment: Thanks to all of you for the clatification and additional remarks. Best regards.